# slim-lang engine line break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I want to use a new-line for each attribute to prettify the code:

```
<%= link_to(
           'New Issue', 
           { :controller => "issues", action: 'new'}, 
           class: 'btn btnsuccess right') %>
```

and I want to do it in slim like:

```
= link_to (
   'New Issue', 
    { :controller => "issues", action: 'new'}, 
    class: 'btn btnsuccess right')
```

with new-lines.

Obviously I am missing something.

Comment: Please take the time to use proper grammar, including capitalization. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum. Instead, you're helping write an online reference book, where grammar and spelling counts. "[ask]" and the linked pages go over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do it without the backslash and keep the code looking a little cleaner. You just have to make sure your first argument is on the same line as `link_to`. Like so:

```
= link_to 'New Issue',
          { :controller => "issues", action: 'new'},
          class: 'btn btnsuccess right'
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it. The answer is the simplest. Just put `\` at the end of the line.

```
= link_to 'New Issue', { :controller => "issues", action: 'new'}, \
  class: 'btn btn-success right'
```